# Is it possible to trigger an event by typing a word?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to trigger an event the moment a word has been typed (without the use of an input field)?

Some elements on the website I am working on have class `.hidden_elements` (display:none). How can class `.open` (display: block) be added to those hidden elements after (at any given time) the word "hello" has been typed.

I have been trying, without luck, this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('body').on('keyup', function() {
    if(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'hello'){
      $('.hidden_elements').addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden_elements {
  display:none;
}

.open {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>
```

Comment: `.addClass(open)`is missing quotes, should be `.addClass('open');`

Comment: If you put `console.log('this', this.value);` insdie the `$('body').on('keyup', function(){` first line, you will see it is undefined. There does not seem to be any value property on the body element. The `keyup` event will not be adding content to body, you will have to have an input element where you have to type the content. Or somehow read the event itself and put the characters one by one in a buffer and check for hello as the final buffer then invoke the business logic to add open class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The following snippet has worked.

The following steps are to be taken

1. Read the event data itself rather the `this.value`. `this.value` on `body` remains undefined
2. Collect the characters typed on the keyboard using the `event.originalEvent.key`
3. After the buffer `buff` length is equal to or greater than 5, check for the last 5 entered characters against the word 'hello'
4. As soon as you enter `hello` it displays the divs by adding the `open` class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  let buff = '';
  $('body').on('keyup', function(event) {
    
    
    buff += event.originalEvent.key;
    // console.log('buff.length', buff.length, buff);
    if (buff.length >= 5) {
      const lastFive = buff.substr(buff.length - 5);
      if(lastFive.toLowerCase() == 'hello') {
        $('.hidden_elements').addClass('open');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden_elements {
  display:none;
}

.open {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        var typed = "", observe = "hello";
        $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
            typed += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which).toLowerCase();
            if (observe.indexOf(typed) != 0) {
                typed = "";
            }
            if (observe == typed) {
                $('.hidden_elements').addClass('open');
                typed = "";
            }
        });
    }());
});
```

```css
.hidden_elements {
    display: none;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Type Hello</p>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>

<div class="hidden_elements">I am hidden</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```